Spring security permit all redirect to /login for any endpoint
Below is the SecurityFilterChain bean created according to the new Spring Security 6 / Spring boot 3 documentation. Please let me know if this is expected or if something is wrong.
code :
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private DomainUserDetailsService domainUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(domainUserDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .headers(headers ->
                        headers
                                .contentSecurityPolicy(csp ->
                                        csp.policyDirectives("default-src 'self' data:;" +
                                                "style-src 'self' maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com getbootstrap.com 'unsafe-inline';"))
                                .frameOptions(frameOptionsConfig -> frameOptionsConfig.deny())
                                .permissionsPolicy(permissions ->
                                        permissions.policy(
                                                "fullscreen=(self), geolocation=(), microphone=(), camera=()"
                                        )
                                )
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizations ->
                        authorizations
                                .requestMatchers("/healthcheck", "/index", "/login", "/register/**", "/h2").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/players/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/players/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/players/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/players/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form ->
                        form.defaultSuccessUrl("/swagger-ui/index.html#/", true)
                );

        return http.build();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class SecurityBeansConfiguration {
    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder getBCE() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    }

}


@RestController
public class UserEntityController {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRep;

    @Autowired
    UserEntityService userService;

    @Autowired
    UserEntityMapper userEntityMapper;

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginForm() {
        return "login";
    }

    // handler method to handle register user form submit request
    @PostMapping("/register/save")
    public String registration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") UserEntityDto user,
                               BindingResult result,
                               Model model) throws LoginAlreadyExistsException {
        UserEntityDto existing = userService.findUserByLastname(user.getLastName());
        if (existing != null) {
            result.rejectValue("email", null, "There is already an account registered with that email");
        }
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            return "register";
        }
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/register?success";
    }

application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:tennis_db
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
##############################
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
server.port=8081

every endpoint I know for example http://localhost:8081/h2 or http://localhost:8081/register always redirects me to http://localhost:8081/login with a spring login and password form security
what should I do and yet I applied permitall on /h2, /register/**, ...

Could you try to add one more thing to configuration part http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()); before return it ?

Show your Spring Security DEBUG logs.

I would suggest modifying the code as suggested by @marcusdacoregio
(Marcus Hert Da Coregio) accordingly. Reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14011
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain( HttpSecurity http , MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {
    http
       .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
       .headers(headers ->
               headers
                     .contentSecurityPolicy(csp ->
                         csp.policyDirectives("default-src 'self' data:;" +
                                                "style-src 'self' maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com getbootstrap.com 'unsafe-inline';"))
                     .frameOptions(frameOptionsConfig -> frameOptionsConfig.deny())
                     .permissionsPolicy(permissions ->
                            permissions.policy(
                                                "fullscreen=(self), geolocation=(), microphone=(), camera=()"
                                        )
                )
       )
       .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
             auth
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/players/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/players/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/players/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/players/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
       )
       .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
             auth
                .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/healthcheck"), mvc.pattern("/index"), mvc.pattern("/login"), mvc.pattern("/register/**"), mvc.pattern("/h2")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
    .formLogin(form ->
                        form.defaultSuccessUrl("/swagger-ui/index.html#/", true))

    return http.build();
}

@Scope("prototype")
@Bean
MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc(HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) {
    return new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
}

